# Object could not be converted to string (laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

My question is, why does the following not work?

```
    $questions = Question::where($queryatypes);

    $questions->get();
```

I'm getting the following Error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be
>   converted to string

Comment: `($queryatypes)` you missing ? and what are `$queryatypes` ??

Comment: $queryatypes is an array, if i put  $questions = Question::where($queryatypes)->get(); the variable works fine

Comment: did u call `use App\Question;` on your file top ?

Comment: yes, if i put $questions = Question::where($queryatypes)->get(); the query works fine but if i put like on the example doesnt work

Comment: and your array `$queryatypes` should be correct way ex : `['site_id' => $siteId]`

Comment: Well, the solution is $questions = $questions->get(); i dont save the data :)

Comment: Plz check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the answer

```
$questions = Question::where($queryatypes);
$questions = $questions->get();
```

Comment: @ManuelBoludaGonzalez :)

Comment: in my case Property [get] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying this on your controller and return this Objects directly

> use Illuminate\Http\Response;

```
public function controllerFunction(){
    $queryatypes = .....
    $questions = Question::where($queryatypes);
    $questions->get();
    return response($questions);
}
```